# Why cant I save and load these serialized variables properly?

Tags: java, android, serialization, fileinputstream

Ok I will try to make this clear as possible. I hope it doesn't get flagged before I get an answer.

I am trying to serialize a class for saving which works just fine. But some of the variables are not getting loaded correctly. Here is the code:
I also marked out places where the code is working and not working.

EDIT: Simplified code a bit more.

Class im saving: (Simple version of it)

```
public class classToSave implements Serializable {


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5184436214950145051L;

public static List<classToSave> classtosavelist = new ArrayList<classToSave>();

public static classToSave one   = new OtherClass1("1", 1, 1, null, Item.1, 1); 
public static classToSave two   = new OtherClass1("2", 1, 2, one , Item.2, 1);  
public static classToSave three = new OtherClass2("3", 1, 4, two , Item.3, 2);

public boolean done = false;     < WONT LOAD/SAVE
public int lvl = 0;              < WONT LOAD/SAVE
transient protected String name; < OK
protected int Xpos;              < OK 
protected int Ypos;              < OK
public Skill parent;             < OK
protected Item item;             < OK
public int extra = 0;            < OK (This Works..)



public classToSave(String s, int x, int y, Skill parent, Item item, int cost) {
    this.name = s;
    this.Xpos = x;
    this.Ypos = y;
    if(parent != null) {
        this.Xpos += parent.Xpos;
        this.Ypos += parent.Ypos;
    }
    this.parent = parent;
    this.item = item;
    add(this, s);
}

private void add(classToSave classtosave, String name) {
    boolean flag = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < skills.size(); i++) {
        if(classtosavelist.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    if(flag) {
        classtosavelist.add(classtosave);
    }
}

public int needPoints() {
    return 1 + extra;
}

public boolean Done(int points) {
    if(points >= needPoints()) {
        this.done = true;
    }
    return this.done;
}

public int getLevel() {
    return this.lvl;
}

public int MAXLevel() {
    return 1;
}

public void LevelUp() {
    if(this.lvl < MAXLevel()) {
        this.lvl++;
    }
}

public void Reset() {
    this.lvl = 0;
}

public Item getRenderItem() {
    return this.item;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public Skill getParent() {
    return this.parent;
}

public boolean isCompleteDone() {
    return (getLevel() == MAXLevel() && done);
}
```

Here is the save and load:

```
private ClassToSave classtosave;


private void save(String savename) {
    if (externalStorageWriteable) {
        try {
            File file = new File(ctxt.getExternalFilesDir(null), savename);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            os.writeObject(classtosave);

            os.flush();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void load(String savename) throws ClassNotFoundException, StreamCorruptedException, IOException {
    if (externalStorageAvailable) {
        File file = new File(ctxt.getExternalFilesDir(null), savename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);


        ClassToSave classtosave = (ClassToSave) is.readObject();

             for (int i=0; i < classtosave.classtosavelist.size(); i++) {
                 classtosave.classtosavelist.get(i).Done(classtosave.classtosavelist.get(i).needPoints()); < WORKS
                 classtosave.classtosavelist.get(i).isCompleteDone(); < DOENST WORK
                 classtosave.classtosavelist.get(i).getLevel();  < DOESNT WORK


                 if (classtosave.classtosavelist.get(i).done == true){ <DOESNT WORK
                    classtosave.classtosavelist.get(i).done = true;
                    classtosave.classtosavelist.get(i).LevelUp();
                 }

             }

        }

        is.close();

}
```

Sorry if brackets are out of place. This code was butchered(Renamed and modified) to make it more readable.

But basically this code is used for a "Skill tree" and what it is supposed to do is save if said skill is complete or not.

If this needs fixed let me know. I can also provide more code as needed.

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue. I.e. continue your butchery a little further until you have a handful of classes that compile (in isolation) where one of them contains a `main` method that triggers the issue.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. Would I need to convert this to work on PC because this is Android.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor misses the boolean and the int. It should be like this :

```
public classToSave(boolean done, int lvl, String s, int x, int y, Skill parent, Item 
item, int cost) {
     this.done = done;
     this.lvl = lvl;
     ...
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. It may have to do with how I am loading it now?

Comment: Same thing. Only the int Extra is getting saved and loaded correctly.

Comment: Unless you have customized the readObject() and writeObject() in your class classToSave, you also need getters for all your parameters. You can also use setters if you do not want to modify your constructor.